# Why is the central charge $c=9$ supersymmetry in the internal manifold?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, compactification, calabi-yau

In [2] (abstract [here]) (https://inspirehep.net/record/245643?ln=en) they say that, when compactifying any superstring theory, the six dimensional internal manifold must have $N=2$ supersymmetry with central charge $c=9$.
 I have seen this stated before (*e.g.* in [1](abstract [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321389902502))), but did not find any references justifying it.

---

[1] Gepner, Doron. "Space-time supersymmetry in compactified string theory and superconformal models." Current Physics–Sources and Comments. Vol. 4. Elsevier, 1989. 381-402. (Page 771)
[2] Kazama, Yoichi, and Hisao Suzuki. "New N= 2 superconformal field theories and superstring compactification." Nuclear Physics B 321.1 (1989): 232-268. (Page 233)

Answer (score 4):

The critical dimension of the superstring is $d=10$, fixed by the conformal anomaly. The total central charge for the world sheet conformal theory is therefore
\begin{equation}
c=d\left(1_\text{scalar}+\frac{1}{2}_\text{fermion}\right)=10 \times\frac{3}{2}=15.
\end{equation}
From the spacetime point of view we want to compactify on a manifold
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{M}_{10}=\mathbb{R}^{1,3} \times M_6
\end{equation}
which amounts to studying a tensor product of conformal $N=2$ theories, in which central charges add. So the $4$ scalar fields and their superpartners in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ contribute
\begin{equation}
c_{\mathbb{R}^{1,3}}=4\times 3/2=6
\end{equation}
and the remaining central charge of $15-6=9$ has to come from degrees of freedom in the internal manifold. That is, the theory of the internal manifold has to be described by a $N=2$ conformal theory of central charge 9.

**Comment on $N=2$:**
If you start out writing down a generic worldsheet sigma-model for an internal space it is in general neither supersymmetric nor conformal. It can be shown that $N=2$ (or $N=(2,2)$ depending on notation) symmetry of the sigma model, corresponds to the internal space being a complex Kähler manifold. On top of that, conformal invariance requires it to be Ricci flat. These two conditions describe a Calabi-Yau manifold.

In other words, if you want to preserve SUSY by compactifying on a Calabi-Yau manifold, from the spacetime point of view, it corresponds to a superconformal $N=2$ theory on the worldsheet.

For technical details I would refer to Brian Greene's lectures (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9702155.pdf) page 49, and references therein.

Comment: Thanks, I get why $c=9$ now, but why $N=2$ SUSY on the worksheet?

Comment: I added a comment to my answer.

Comment: Two last questions: 
1. From your comment, $N=2$ SUSY on the worldsheet implies that the internal manifold is Calabi-Yau. Do you know if the converse statement is also true? (Calabi-Yau implies $N=2$?)
2. Accepting that we need wordsheet $N=2$ SUSY, how does this mean that compactification "amounts to studying a tensor product of conformal $N=2$ theories"?

Comment: Since the theories are $N=2$ superconformal, should,t you get $c_{\mathbb{R}^{1,3}} = 4\times (1+1/2+1/2)$ (because you have two fermions for each boson)?